# Positioning two child div inside parent div

Tags: html, css

SO I have parent `div` which holds two child `div`, one holds anchors the other one holds pictures.
I have problem moving child `div` to the right of the screen.
I want to move these 2 `div` to the right of the screen inline.
Which way is the more practical, to push it with margin, use positioning or flexbox?

```
.parent {
  float: right;
}

.child1-img, 
.child2-anchor {   
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent{
  background:#fff;
  height:40vh;
  width:50vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: flex-end;
  padding:10px;
}

.child1, .child2{
  height:25vh;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child2">2</div>
    </div>
```

Check whether it's working for you. And the same I've written in codepen too. https://codepen.io/ak228212/pen/QWajNzj

Comment: I was trying to avoid flexbox since it's a menu with anchor links and some images(nothing big).
I finished menu by simply putting
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
On the two divs I have in menu.
But this was really helpful,since I just started learning flexbox.

Comment: Sounds great, as my answer helps you. But, I think this is a good way to do that.